# Mocking SecurityContext in Symfony2 using PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

These are my mocks:

```
$this->user->method('getCustomerId')
           ->willReturn($this->customerId);
$this->userToken->method('getUser')
                ->willReturn($this->user);
$this->securityContext->method('getToken')
                      ->willReturn($this->userToken);
$this->securityContext->expects($this->once())
                      ->method('isGranted')
                      ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

And this is the code of the class I am testing:

```
$token = $securityContext->getToken();
$isFullyAuthenticated = $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
```

It throws the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: The security context contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.
```

I have no idea what to do at this point, I though mocks intercepted the call to methods and returned whatever I wanted. But in this case is seems the isGranted methods is not being mock

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own. Just create an instance and put a token inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is that the `isGranted` method is final, so it's imposible to mock, the workaround the problem was to mock all the attributes of SecurityContext so that when the method is call it returns my desired output, instead of intercepting the call with a mock method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `willReturn` instead of `will` and add the `with`

So try this:

```
$this->securityContext->expects($this->once())
                      ->method('isGranted')
                      ->with('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')
                      ->willReturn(true);
```

Instead of this:

```
$this->securityContext->expects($this->once())
                      ->method('isGranted')
                      ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

Hope this help